# Unable to show modal popup when LDAP authentication failed

Tags: php, ldap, bootstrap-modal

I am working to validate users from LDAP via PHP. I have tried some code and I can now validate users perfectly. But in the case of an unsuccessful login, I want to display a modal popup with some custom message. Here is my code -

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // username and password sent from form 

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    //print($username);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //print($password);
    // using ldap bind

    $ldaprdn  = 'uid=' .$username. ',ou=People,ou=AP,o=abcd.com'; // ldap rdn or dn
    $ldappass = $password;

    // connect to ldap server
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect("ad.abcd.com") or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

    if ($ldapconn) {

        try {
    $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
} catch (Exception $e) {

    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#myModal').modal('show');</script>";
                //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#myModal').fadeIn('show');</script>";
                echo "<script>
         $(window).load(function(){
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
         });
    </script>";
}
        if ($ldapbind) {

            $filter = '(sAMAccountName='.$username.')';
            $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, "(cn=*)") or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result); 
            $userDN = $entries[0]["ikealegacyuid"][0];          

            echo ('<p style="color:green;">I have the user DN: '.$userDN.'</p>');
            $url = 'Location: logpage01.html?uid=' .$userDN;
            echo $url;
            header($url);
        } else {
         //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#myModal').modal('show');</script>";
                //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#myModal').fadeIn('show');</script>";
                echo "<script>
         $(window).load(function(){
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
         });
    </script>";
        }

    }

}
?>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style type = "text/css">
         body {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
         }
         label {
            font-weight:bold;
            width:100px;
            font-size:14px;
         }
         .box {
            border:#666666 solid 1px;
         }
      </style>

   </head>

   <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">

      <div align = "center">
         <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
            <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>

            <div style = "margin:30px">

               <form action = "" method = "post">
                  <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
                  <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
               </form>



            </div>

         </div>

      </div>
      <div class="container">

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> -->
          <h4 class="modal-title">System Message : Failure</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Sorry !! Something went wrong. Please contact your administrator.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="window.location.href = 'logpage01.html';">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

   </body>
</html>
```

I tried many solutions found here. But nothing worked. Need some help on this.

**UPDATE:** Checked Page Source Also. Seems it's fine. If not, please let me know the issue.
[image]

I tried to call modal on page load also. It is working perfectly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the page source to see exactly what HTML is generated? Is it valid?

Comment: Yes. It is generating. Modified Main section with image.

Comment: Remove the `@` operator when calling `ldap_bind()`.

Comment: Throwing error like this - Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in C:\xampp\htdocs\Log_Check\login.php on line 23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just echoing the script won't work here, at best your browser will end up running a script that references `$` before loading the html that loads jQuery, so even if it runs your script it will throw `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Instead you can use a flag to tell the browser whether or not to show the modal. For example, you can set a variable in your else (and catch) statement :

```
if ($ldapbind) { /*...*/ }
else {
  $access_denied=1;
}
```

and insert it into the html so that the browser knows it must load the modal when `access_denied===1`, for this you also need to add the script that will load the modal only under that condition :

```
<div id="myModal" access_denied="<?php print $access_denied ?>" > ... </div>
<script> 
  $('#myModal[access_denied=1]').modal('show');
</script>
```

In another context using ajax requests you would probably just echo some json or output the modal html directly.

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly you are missing popper.js which is required in bootstrap. Please check this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/ and you will get an online cdn for popper which you can use. Or simply copy my snippet. Please also be aware that you are using bootstrap in version 3. I highly recommend using V4.

In php you have to just echo the following when you want to show the modal.

```
echo "<script>
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
       </script>";
```

```js
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> -->
          <h4 class="modal-title">System Message : Failure</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Sorry !! Something went wrong. Please contact your administrator.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="window.location.href = 'logpage01.html';">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions. Still, somehow it's not working. I have added Page Source also in Main Question.

Comment: Have you tried to open it directly with jquery without echoing?

Comment: Yes. It is working. Updated main question with Jquery also.